# Excel round multiple dates to a single one

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to put multiple rows which contain a date of the month between the first and last day of the month and I want to put them togeather as the first of the month dpeending on which month they are in:

for example; if they have the month of 12 i want to make them the 01/12/2020 if it was november 01/11/2020 and so on...

What i am looking for is to get three or more dates into a single one:

| Date |
| --- |
| 03/12/2020 |
| 16/12/2020 |
| 27/12/2020 |

And make it:

| Date |
| --- |
| 01/12/2020 |

Thanks for any help on how i could go about this, im struggling to find a solution

(I have tried text join and concatenate and neither work)

Comment: Welcome to SO! The example is not very clear, you should add some input data and expected result. Most probably `=CONCATENATE("01/",MONTH(A4),"/",YEAR(A4))`, just replace A4 by the cell you try to work with.

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego thanks for the input, howver i have included the expected result you will find it under the "and make it:" section and the input is the table prior to that. also the answer has already been found and explained by TomC and Harun24HR. thanks tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty unconventional way of doing it but works:

```
=EOMONTH(EDATE(AVERAGE(A1:A12),-1),0)+1
```

Where `A1:A12` is a range of dates.

Comment: Brilliant, that worked! never heard of the EOmonth command before, thank you so much!

Comment: I just amended it slightly to make it a little cleaner.

Comment: It will fails if there are dates of different year.

Comment: so what do the -1, 0 and +1 bits do on the end of that code?

Comment: @Ranjar EDATE pulls it back to the previous month so that you can then use EOMONTH and then add 1 day to get the first day of the month in the range.

Comment: @Harun24HR - I would expect this is what Ranjar wants.

Comment: @TomC Just I pointed if OP has different year, otherwise fine!

Comment: @TomC oh sweet awesome, thanks for the explination, super simple!

Comment: I only need it for stuff in the month so across years isnt important, but @Harun24HR I really appreciate the extra info and if I ever need to do across years then I know how to now, thank you both so much! :D

Comment: @Ranjar Great !

Answer (score 1):

If you have <kbd>Excel365</kbd> then use-

```
=DATE(2020,UNIQUE(MONTH(A1:A4)),1)
```

[image]

If you have dates with different years then try below formula.

```
=DATEVALUE("01-"&UNIQUE(TEXT(A1:A4,"mm-yyyy")))
```

Comment: when i try that it tells me its missing a closing parenthesis?

Comment: Check brackets in formula. May be you are missing last bracket.

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified well whether your dates are strings or actual Excel dates. Nor is it clear to me whether this is an example of a single cell in a larger row. The solution would be different based on the answer to these questions (which I do not have enough reputation to put as comments).

If you already have these values as dates put a new value in an adjacent column. Assuming the existing date value is in cell A1:

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1), MONTH(A1), 1)
```

However, if the date value is actually a string you will need to hard code the extraction of the values. Assuming, the are in fixed length strings as your image shows, with `dd/mm/yyyy` format:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A1, 4), MID(A1, 4, 2), 1)
```